# Google Colab でトークン等の秘密データを扱う場合にはどうしたらいいのか？

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

プログラミングでトークンなどの秘密データを扱う際にローカルであれば環境変数などを設定してうまくやると思うのですが、Google Colab (ブラウザ) で行う場合にはどうしたらいいのでしょうか？

自分が考えた案としてはGoogle Driveにトークンなどのテキストファイルをアップロードしそれを `from google.colab import drive` でファイルを読み込むのがいい気がしました。
(トークンをドライブにアップロードしていいのかが微妙?）

[python info 初心者でも忘れないで〜環境変数を利用しよう〜](https://admin-it.xyz/python/python-enviroment-variables/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

私の場合、トークンではないですが秘密データを扱う際は
Google Driveにパスワード付きzipでアップロードしておいて、実行時に
パスワードを入力し解凍して使用しています。

```
import getpass
p = getpass.getpass()
!unzip -P {p} (path-to-file)/xxx.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

グーグルドライブを使用して、あなたはあなたの.pyコードをアップロードすることができます

```
from google.colab import files
src = list(files.upload().values())[0]
open('mykey.py','wb').write(src)
import mykey
key = mykey.key()
```

そしてmykey.pyは次のようになります

```
#mykey.py
def key():
    return 14873987298749827349#キーの例
```

すみません、私の日本語はあまり上手ではありません

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
そのファイルはGoogle Driveにアップロードされますか？